# Endogenous interactions in nonparametric instrumental variables

Tags: nonparametric, econometrics, instrumental-variables, generalized-additive-model

I'm interested in estimating a model along the lines of 
$$
pr(y==1) = g^{-1}\left(f(x_1,x_2)+X'\beta\right)+\epsilon
$$
where $g$ is logit and $f$ is some smooth function.  I'm using GAM's in `mgcv`.  Assume the linearly-entering variables are binary exogenous controls.

The wrinkle:  both continuous variables are endogenous.  In my present problem, I have selection bias -- $y$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ are determined by $\mathbf{e}$, which I don't observe.

But I do have instruments $z_1$ and $z_2$, which I know *a priori* are uncorrelated with $y$, but are correlated with $x_1$ and $x_2$.  If I wanted to estimate

$$
pr(y==1) = g^{-1}\left(f(x_1) +f(x_2)+X'\beta\right)+\epsilon
$$
(i.e.: no interaction), I could estimate 
$$
x_1 = f(z_1)+f(z_2)+X'\beta+\zeta_1\\
x_2 = f(z_1)+f(z_2)+X'\beta+\zeta_2
$$
, then fit
$$
pr(y==1) = g^{-1}\left(f(x_1) +f(x_2) + f(\hat\zeta_1)+ f(\hat\zeta_2)\right)+\epsilon
$$

For a reference on the above, see [this paper by Marra & Radice](http://smj.sagepub.com/content/11/6/581.abstract).

The problem is what to do when I'm interested in an interaction of my continuous variables.  Standard parametric IV would simply instrument for the interaction with the interacted instruments.  But if I'm interested in a smooth interaction -- for example using a tensor product -- it isn't clear how this would work.  Concretely, I want to estimate

```
m = gam(y~te(x1,x2))
```

which is the same as

```
m = gam(y~ti(x1)+ti(x2)+ti(x1,x2))
```

rather than

```
m = gam(y~s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x1x2))
```

So what do I do?  I got the idea that I could simply interact the residuals, using the same basis expansion as I do for the endogenous terms.  So, assuming I've already fit the first stages:

```
m = gam(y~te(x1,x2)+te(zeta1,zeta2))
```

I really don't know if this is legitimate, and will lead to a consistent estimate of $f(x_1,x_2)$.  I'm completely stumped about how to go about determining this analytically.  I have simulated using linear control functions, and I get good results:

```
require(AER)
N <- 1000
noint <-matrix(rep(NA,N*3),N,3)
int <-matrix(rep(NA,N*3),N,3)
IV <-matrix(rep(NA,N*3),N,3)
cfIV <-matrix(rep(NA,N*3),N,3)
for (i in 1:1000){
    z1 <- rnorm(N)
    z2 <- rnorm(N)+z1 
    u <- rnorm(N)
    x1 <- 1 + z1 + u + rnorm(N) # x1 is endogenous
    x2 <- 1 + z2 +x1+ u + rnorm(N) # x2 is both endogenous and correlated with x1
    y <- 1 + x1 - x2 +x1*x2 + u #the true DGP

    xm1 <-lm(x1~z1+z2) #Regress instruments on endogenous variables
    xm2 <-lm(x2~z1+z2)

    zx1 <-residuals(xm1)
    zx2 <-residuals(xm2)

    m = lm(y~x1*x2+zx1*zx2) #Method 2 interacts the residuals of both first-stage regressions
    int[i,]<-c(m$coef[2:3],m$coef[6])
    m = lm(y~x1*x2+zx1+zx2) #Method 1 specifies the residuals of the first stages as additive even though the endigenous variables are interacted
    noint[i,]<-c(m$coef[2:3],m$coef[5])

    m = ivreg(y~x1*x2|z1*z2) #In standard IV methodology, an interaction between endogenous variables is instrumented with an interaction between the instruments
    IV[i,]<-c(m$coef[2:4])

    #Replicating the above via control functions
    x1x2 <- x1*x2
    xm1 <-lm(x1~z1*z2) #Regress instruments on endogenous variables
    xm2 <-lm(x2~z1*z2)
    xm3 <- lm(x1x2~z1*z2)

    zx1 <-residuals(xm1)
    zx2 <-residuals(xm2)
    zx3 <-residuals(xm3)
    m = lm(y~x1+x2+x1x2+zx1+zx2+zx3) #Method 2 interacts the residuals of both first-stage regressions
    cfIV[i,]<-m$coef[2:4]

}
par(mfrow=c(4,3))
hist(noint[,1]-1)
abline(v=mean(noint[,1]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(noint[,2]+1)
abline(v=mean(noint[,2]+1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(noint[,3])
abline(v=mean(noint[,3]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')

hist(int[,1]-1)
abline(v=mean(int[,1]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(int[,2]+1)
abline(v=mean(int[,2]+1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(int[,3]-1)
abline(v=mean(int[,3]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=1,col='red')

hist(IV[,1]-1)
abline(v=mean(IV[,1]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(IV[,2]+1)
abline(v=mean(IV[,2]+1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(IV[,3]-1)
abline(v=mean(IV[,3]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=1,col='red')

hist(cfIV[,1]-1)
abline(v=mean(cfIV[,1]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(cfIV[,2]+1)
abline(v=mean(IV[,2]+1),col='blue')
abline(v=0,col='red')
hist(cfIV[,3]-1)
abline(v=mean(cfIV[,3]-1),col='blue')
abline(v=1,col='red')
```

The result is here:
[image]

My interacted-residuals approach is on the second row -- parameter estimates appear unbiased.  It also seems quite a bit more efficient than the standard approach, given in the 3rd and 4th columns, which are identical:

```
1> all.equal(IV,cfIV)
[1] TRUE
```

**So my question**:  Is an interaction of the residuals of the first-stage regressions a valid way to adjust for the endogeneity of an interaction of endogenous variables?  How can I be certain?  Is it possible to show this analytically?  Are there any circumstances that my dummy DGP might be missing?  What assumptions might I need that I don't realize?

Or: is there anything completely elementary that I'm missing?  I often find that my complicated questions are deflated by stupid mistakes :)